# Notepadqq icons&font changed after update Ubuntu

Tags: icons, notepadqq

After the latest update from Ubuntu's Software update for Notepadqq on Ubuntu 16.04, the application's icons and font (not editor's font) had changed. Why and how I'm going back? I'll attach a screenshot (top)  with the original icons on Ubuntu and another one  (bottom) with the ones after the update.
[image: default icons&font]

[image: new icons&font]

Answer (score 1):

I can't confirm this (I'm using Notepadqq 1.3.4-1~xenial1 on Xenial).

But you can change Notepadqq theme back in its settings:

1. Open *Settings* menu
2. Click *Preferences*
3. On *Appearance* section set *Color scheme* to *Default*:

   [image: Appearance]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but unfortunately it's not the case: the color scheme applies only on the editor, it's not for the icons and application's main font (not the editor's font). I had the same dark theme before so it's not the case.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very late reply, but in case anyone else stumbles upon this.
The window design seems to be controlled by the systems QT settings, not by notepadqq itself. The design can thus be changed with for example the Qt5 Configuration tool